# Create annotation via CRM Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi

Anyone knows how to create an "annotation" using CRM Web API.  I can create other objects such as account and contacts but annotation attachment is a no go. Seems like my object is missing something.

```
    JObject notes = null;
            notes = new JObject();

            notes["isdocument"] = true;
            notes["objecttypecode"] = "mfr_ownermlslistingwaiver";
            notes["ownerid@odata.bind"] = "/systemusers(E94126AC-64FB-E211-9BED-005056920E6D)";
            notes["owneridtype"] = 8;
            notes["documentbody"] = "/9j/4VmjRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAANAAABBAABAAAAIBAAAAEBB...";
            notes["minetype"] = "image/jpeg";
            notes["filename"] ="2213 Scrub Jay Rd.jpg";
            notes["objectid@odata.bind"] = "/mfr_ownermlslistingwaivers(137C660B-ADAA-E711-80CD-005056927DF7)"; 
HttpResponseMessage createResponse =
              await httpClient.SendAsJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "annotations", notes);
```

Comment: are you receiving an error of any kind off of the post?  Maybe try sending it synchronously to see what happens.  Also, have you consulted this example? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328429.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create annotation to a contact entity in Microsoft Dynamics CRM by API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761311/create-annotation-to-a-contact-entity-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-by-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have couple of issues in code.
1. Typo in mimetype
2. Incorrect Single valued navigation property - objectid@odata.bind and it should be objectid_[entity]@odata.bind

Necessary properties should look like below:

```
note["notetext"] = "Invoice Report Attached"
note["subject"] = "Invoice";
note["filename"] = "Invoice.pdf";
note["mimetype"] = "application/pdf";
note["objectid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(C5DDA727-B375-E611-80C8-00155D00083F)";
note["documentbody"] = [base64String];
```

[Reference](http://d365solutions.blogspot.com/2017/01/create-noteannotation-with-attachment.html?m=1) & [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32761311/7920473)