# Can I create two entities and then a third linking entity atomically using Web API in Dynamics?

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm developing a NodeJS app which queries Dynamics 365 using the Web API (oData).

I need to create an `account` entity, a `contact` entity and then a `connection` entity which will link the two together. I would like this to happen atomically so that if any of these fail, then they all fail.

The `connection` entity needs to know the `accountid` and `contactid` in advance, which means it must occur after the creation of the `account` and the `contact`

I'm aware of the [batch command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api) which lets you create multiple entities atomically but it does not look like I can pass the result of one request to the payload of another.

Is it possible to do such a request atomically over a web interface and if not, what fallbacks could I use to approximate atomic transactions?

Comment: Yes it was, I have upvoted although hasn’t fully solved my problem, for example in my actual use case I need to create two connection entities atomically which I don’t think is possible this way. I’m leaving it open in case further answers bubble up

Comment: Part 3 of my answer from the linked SO thread in my answer below talks about reading the returned id & using in next api call. It may help your atomic record creation scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing around with deep insert for a bit but didn't get anywhere - @Arun do you think you could comment [on this new question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790306)?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly - You should be able to achieve this by [Deep insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328090(v%3Dcrm.8)#create-related-entities-in-one-operation).

Part 3 of my answer in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644021/7920473) talks about reading the returned id & using in next api call. It may help your atomic record creation scenarios.