# Why is deep insert failing when trying to create a Contact and Account entities through a Connection in Dynamics WebAPI

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have been able to create a contact in Dynamics WebAPI using a payload similar to this ...

```
{ 
     "firstname": "asd",
     "lastname": "asd"
}
```

I have been able to create an Account entity in Dynamics WebAPI using a payload similar to this ...

```
{
    "name":"SOLE TRADER ORG",
    "emailaddress1":"otbpostman1@post.com",
    "telephone1":"07188888"
}
```

and a Connection entity between the two as follows ...

```
{
    "record1roleid@odata.bind":"/connectionroles(1EB54AB1-58B7-4D14-BF39-4F3E402616E8)",
    "record2roleid@odata.bind":"/connectionroles(35A23B91-EC62-41EA-B5E5-C59B689FF0B4)",
    "record1id_contact@odata.bind":"/contacts(645f6455-8f1d-e911-a847-000d3ab4f534)", 
    "record2id_account@odata.bind":"/accounts(233cf761-8f1d-e911-a847-000d3ab4f534)"
}
```

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/create-entity-web-api#create-related-entities-in-one-operation) I should be able to do a deep insert where I can atomically create all three in one request, I have tried the following ...

```
{
    "record1roleid@odata.bind":"/connectionroles(1EB54AB1-58B7-4D14-BF39-4F3E402616E8)",
    "record2roleid@odata.bind":"/connectionroles(35A23B91-EC62-41EA-B5E5-C59B689FF0B4)",
    "record1id_contact": { 
      "firstname": "asd",
      "lastname": "asd"
    }, 
    "record2id_account": {
      "name":"SOLE TRADER ORG",
      "emailaddress1":"otbpostman1@post.com",
      "telephone1":"07188888"
    }
}
```

... as well a bunch of variations around this but with no luck. I keep getting errors of type ...

> "code": "0x80048210",
>   "message": "Both objects being connected are missing."

Have I missed some key feature that means this is or is not possible?

Comment: I will test in CRM Rest Builder & let you know.

Comment: I tried from my end. Only the 3rd payload above is working, probably having parameterize the GUIDs after creating the account/contact separately should work. But cannot be rolled back.

Comment: Too many hoops it has to jump, this is more like a many to many intersect entity creating the associated records on the fly & the reciprocal record of the connection as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think record2id_account is expecting a guid, so that wont work,

as the page you linked says, they do it on opportunity, they use

"An opportunity is created because it is defined as an object within an array that is set to the value of a ***collection-valued navigation property opportunity_customer_accounts***."

for contacts i can guess it's ***contact_customer_accounts*** and ***contact_customer_contacts*** maybe?

this will hopefully create everything at once, but how to associate to the connection is a another problem.

without testing, something like this could work:

```
{
"record1roleid@odata.bind":"/connectionroles(1EB54AB1-58B7-4D14-BF39-4F3E402616E8)",
"record2roleid@odata.bind":"/connectionroles(35A23B91-EC62-41EA-B5E5-C59B689FF0B4)",
"record1id_contact": { 
 "contact_customer_contacts":
   [
   {
  "firstname": "asd",
  "lastname": "asd"
   }
   ]
}, 
"record2id_account": {
"contact_customer_accounts":
   [
   {
  "name": "SOLE TRADER",
  "emailaddress1":"otbpostman1@post.com",
  "telephone1":"07188888"
   }
   ]
}
}
```

Comment: `account_connections1` and `contact_connections2` are the right properties, good try but still failing.. :(

Comment: Yeah, im not sure you are allowed to create and associate in the same request, during deep insert?