# Dynamics CRM Mobile Activity Forms Attachments

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is it possible to upload attachments/files in the activity mobile forms (tasks, appointments etc) in Dynamics CRM?

[image]

Comment: Is this Field service Resco app or Canvas app or custom built page? Probably you have to add/edit this app to include the Notes section somehow. Check with someone is your team

Comment: It's the out of box form.

Comment: Did you see my form? Do you know what CRM version you have..?

Comment: Gotcha, I think you’re in old version - https://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/use-dynamics-crm-mobile-app-on-mobile-device/ which is retired and latest version is better.

Comment: I’ll update the answer. Upvote/accept to close this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

The app in question is old version of Dynamics 365 for mobile app, which is retired now and modern UCI mobile app has better functionality.

———————————————————

You have to first create the activity record (task/appointment) before attaching files in Notes or attachment section, since they are child records and can be associated to parent activity record once the parent is created.

In other words, quick create or OOB create forms cannot furnish your requirement.

Alternately, you have to develop a custom HTML form where you can collect all the information and files, and then creating CRM records (both parent and child) on your own using CRM web api deep insert at one shot.

[Read my SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644021/7920473)

This is how UCI mobile App Notes section will look like:

[image]

Comment: In mobile forms, after I create the activity and the note, I do not see where I can attach a file.

Comment: @Pliskin, pls check this thread for clarity - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/155131/attach-files-to-a-case-incident

Comment: Thank you, Arun, but I am looking for a way to attach files to activity/notes in MOBILE forms and I do not think it is possible. Thank you.

Comment: @Pliskin I know, I want you to understand that once Activity parent is created - then you can create the Child Note (annotation) including a file attachment. If you’re looking for subgrid in quick create form, that’s not possible. In Mobile form if it’s full entity form then possible. Adding screenshot will be helpful in your question

Comment: Thank you, Arun. What I am trying to explain is that in mobile when I create the Activity parent, and then create the annotation, there is no option to include a file attachment.

Comment: @Pliskin can you add screenshot to question??

Comment: Hi Arun, I have added a screenshot of a sample mobile notes screen. As you can see, there is no option to add an attachment.